# Why are Neural Network Loss Functions Always Positive

Tags: neural-network, loss-function

I am trying to fill a gap in my knowledge. In looking at the majority of loss functions for neural networks, such as mse, mae, L1, L2, the loss is always recorded as a positive value. What I don't understand is why? Shouldn't the loss function have positive or negative values in order to raise or lower the weights of the network as needed?

Comment: Loss function detects how big is your mistake. If you have no mistake, it's 0. It doesn't make sense for it to be negative. To raise or lower the weights you need derivatives to be positive or negative, and they can be like this.

Answer (score 1):

Loss functions like Mean Squared Error ( MSE ) function always give positive loss values. They tend to display whether how big the error is and not where is it done.

> Suppose our Neural Network is a basketball player. Its task is to
>   throw the ball in the basket. If the ball falls to the left of the
>   basket, the error is negative. But, if it falls to the right, the
>   error is positive. If it falls in the basket, the error is 0. This
>   approach was followed by earlier loss functions. In this case, MSE
>   gives a positive loss and gives the loss regarding that the ball has
>   not reached the basket. It does not bother about whether the ball fell
>   to the right or left of the basket.

Comment: I guess my hang up is that I think of it in the previous terms of left or right. Will the network be able to automatically correct its shot, without knowing of if it missed to the left or right of the target? Its ability to do so is where I vecome confused and have doubts.